# How can I automatically add a foreign key to a table on select which is stored in an associated other?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, database-schema

I have a database with some tables among which these 3:

```
organizations
    organization_id PK
teams
    team_id PK
    team_organization_id FK
users
    user_id PK
teams_users
    tu_id PK
    tu_team_id FK
    tu_user_id FK
```

So:

- Team belongs to Organization
- Organization has many Teams
- User has and belongs to many Teams
- Team has and belongs to many Users

And, consequently User has to belong to an Unique Organization. When I select some users, I would want to know (always) to which organization it depends.

What is the best way to deal with this ?

I think for now that perfect solution would be if I could get the `organization_id` called for example `user_organization_id` in my all select results on users.

Am I true on this point ? How to do that correctly ?

My database runs on PostgreSQL (9.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I select some users, I would want to know (always) to which
>   organization it depends.

Use joins:

```
SELECT u.*, t.team_organization_id AS organization_id
FROM   users       u
JOIN   teams_users tu ON tu_user_id = u.user_id;
JOIN   teams       t  ON t.team_id = tu.tu_team_id
WHERE  tu_user_id = $user_id;
```

To get that *automatically*, you could create a `VIEW` encapsulating the query:

```
CREATE VIEW usr_org As
<query from above>
```

Then instead of `SELECT * FROM users`, use:

```
SELECT * FROM usr_org;
```

[More about views in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html)

Comment: Ok, so my question become: what is the good way to automatically add the `organization_id` to each select done on the `users` table, rather that doing this join for each select statement. Should I define a trigger ?

Comment: @RémiB.: There are not triggers for `SELECT`. You probably want a `VIEW`.